# Sorting alphanumeric data with letters before numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

Problem: How to sort with the appearance of mainframe sorting which uses EBCDIC characters.

I have been searching for an answer to this for three days and nothing has worked.
I have about 6,000 lines of part numbers. I need Excel to sort them by letter first, then by number (throughout the entire part number). The part numbers are not consistent in length and do not have any constant values.

Excel does this:

```
E7NND550AB
E7NND561CA
E8NND749AA
E9NN10316AA
EAA6889B
EAF907B
EC0N585A
```

I need this:

```
EAA6889B
EAF907B
EC0N585A
E7NND550AB
E7NND561CA
E8NND749AA
E9NN10316AA
```

PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 1):

A Custom Sort Order **should** do the trick, but I can't get it to work. So, the next approach is to temporarily translate the data.

From [David McRitchie's Excel page](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/sorting.htm#ebcdic):

> How to sort with the appearance of mainframe sorting which uses EBCDIC characters.

Create this function:

```
Function SortBCD(aaa)
   'David McRitchie  1999-04-07
   '  see sorting in http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel.htm
   'Sort letters before numbers as in BCD and in EBCDIC.
   'FromSTR is comprised of characters to be sorted must in EBCDIC sequence
   'See http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/rexx/htm/symbols.htm    
   FromSTR = " -/=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
   'Sortstr any characters but must be in EXCEL sequence
   'Please note EXCEL sequence differs from ASCII
   'Must be at least as long as FromSTR
   SortSTR = "#$()0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
   L = Len(aaa)
   capsaaa = UCase(aaa)   'bonus: will treat LCase same as UCase
   For i = 1 To Len(capsaaa)
       For j = 1 To Len(FromSTR)
          If Mid(capsaaa, i, 1) = Mid(FromSTR, j, 1) Then
             SortBCD = SortBCD & Mid(SortSTR, j, 1)
             GoTo nextI
          End If
       Next j
nextI:
   Next i
End Function
```

> To use create a column next to source column and use formula such as   =SortBCD(A1)   then sort data on the new column.  Once sorted remove the new column which is nonsensible gibberish used to help sorting and is no longer useful once sorted.  If you make changes to the formula don't forget to hit F9 for recalculation before resorting.

Comment: Thank you, I already found that and it didn't work for me.

Comment: What didn't work? I was able to get it to work with your sample data. Did the function translate the values, but they still didn't sort they way you want? Or did the function not translate the values?

Comment: Well, I'm guessing there is much not being said there for someone who has virtually zero experience with Visual Basics or macros.
What I did:
Alt + F11, copied and pasted function
Now what??
Inserted a new column, tried using formula =SortBCD(D2)
because cell D2 is where my sorting begins.
But Excel won't recognize it as a formula, so when I fill down, they simply repeat D2 instead of cell by cell.
I have no idea how to make this work without more information.

Comment: I figured it out. Turns out that Macros created as User Defined Functions don't run if CAPS LOCK is on! I had no idea. So, it did work. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear that it works. Did you have your macro assigned to a shortcut key that was lowercase? That would explain why it didn't run when CapsLock was on. But I'm not sure why a macro was involved. If you had the function in a module in the editor (Alt+F11), it should be usable in a cell without needing a macro.